# How can I fix website opening in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

So I am building an HTML website, and I have 3 sections in total, the editor part, FaQ & Contact. And for some reason every time I open my website, the website will start at the Contact Section and not the Editor one on which it should... I tried everything, searching in Google, YouTube, and even personally searching for a solution in the code, but haven't found one so far...

Below is the code if someone needs it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>How2CodeEditor.com</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family:'Inter';
            }
            textarea, iframe 
            {
                border: 1px solid #404040;
                height: 700px;
                width: 100%;
                font-family: 'Courier New';
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            .code-window {
                border:1px solid #404040;
            }

            .CodeMirror {
                font-family: 'Courier New';
                height: 700px;
                font-size: 20px;
                max-width:1200px;
            }
            
            .btn-run 
            {
                padding:8px;
                background-color:#22aadd;
                border:none;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                border-radius:2px;
                transition:all 0.3s;
            }
            
            .btn-run:hover
            {
                background-color:#404040;
            }
            ::-webkit-input-placeholder
body
{
    font-family: "Inter", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #777;
    background: #7acceb;
}

.container
{
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#contact .logo img
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
}

#contact
{
    background: #F9F9F9;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact .head-paragraph
{
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

#contact input, #contact textarea, #contact .btn-submit
{
    font-family: "Inter", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact input, #contact textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact input:hover, #contact textarea:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #22aadd;
}

#contact .field
{
    border: medium none !important;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#contact textarea
{
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    resize: none;
}

#contact .btn-submit
{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: #4ebbe4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact .btn-submit:hover
{
    background: #22aadd;
}

#contact .btn-submit:active
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#contact .copyright
{
    text-align: center;
}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
        <a href="https://how2code.netlify.app" target="_blank">
        <img src="How2Code.png" alt="#" style="max-width:120px; max-height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
        </a>
        <br>
        <div style="padding:10px 10px; border:1px solid #000000;">
            <h1 align="center">How2Code Editor&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="49%">
                        <h4>This is Your Code Here&nbsp; :
                        <input onclick="runCode();" class="btn-run" type="button" value="Run Code" style="float:right;"></h4>
                        <form style="border:1px solid #dddddd;">
                            <textarea name="sourceCode" id="sourceCode"></textarea>
                      </form>
                  </td>
                    <td width="2%"></td>
                    <td width="49%">
                        <h4>This Is The Result of Your Code&nbsp; :<span style="color:green;">&nbsp;</span></h4>
                        <iframe name="targetCode" id="targetCode"></iframe>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("sourceCode"), {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "xml",
                autoCloseTags:true
            });
            
            function runCode()
            {
                var content = editor.getDoc().getValue("\n");
                var iframe = document.getElementById('targetCode');
                iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow :
                (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document :
                iframe.contentDocument;
                iframe.document.open();
                iframe.document.write(content);
                iframe.document.close();
                return false;
            }
            runCode();
        </script>
    <br><br>
    <hr>
    <br><br>
    <h2>Top 5 most asked questions about our Editor :</h2>
            <br>
            <h4><b> • What is How2CodeEditor.com?</b></h4>
            <p>How2CodeEditor.com is an online HTMl, CSS or JavaScript Editor developed by How2Code™ Group LTD.</p>
            <h4><b> • How to use this editor?</b></h4>
            <p>To use this editor, find the "Editor" section. After that in the field on the left type in your code, and it will be displayed in the right box.</p>
            <h4><b> • How to Run the Commands?</b></h4>
            <p>To run the code, click the "Run Code" button above the left field / box.</p>
            <h4><b> • Why don't the images display in the editor?</b></h4>
            <p>The images are not displaying in the right box because we don't have your selected image in the same folder as our source code.</p>
            <h4><b> • Why don't some other coding languages work in here such as jQuery, Python, C#, C++, etc. ?</b></h4>
            <p>Because this editor is specificly for HTML, CSS, JavaScript & PhP. Nothing else for now. We are currently working on implementing more coding languages to the editor!</p>
    <hr>
            <br><br>
    <h2>Sign-Up for Live Lessons with How2Code :</h2>
    <div class="container">
            <form id="contact" action="https://formspree.io/f/myylenpy" method="POST">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img alt="Logo" src="How2Code.png" />
                </div>
                <h3 class="head-paragraph">Sign Up for live lessons!</h3>
                <br>
                <div class="field">
                    <input placeholder="Your Full Name / UserName . . ." type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input placeholder="Your E-Mail Address . . ." type="email" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional) . . ." type="tel" tabindex="1">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input placeholder="Your Website URL . . ." type="url" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <textarea placeholder="Type your message here . . ." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <button name="submit" class="btn-submit">Sign Up!</button>
                <h6 align="center"><span style="color:red;">We will contact you in the next 24 hours after your submission!</span></h6>
            </form>
    <br>
    </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because in your input field you added an attribute called `autofocus`. Remove it and the page will load from top.

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a picture of text.